# How and why did R. Akiva Eiger try to emulate the Rashba?

Tags: rishonim, acharonim, rashba, rav-akiva-eiger

I'm attending a *bar mitzva* celebration recently, and the father of the boy gives a short speech. During his speech he mentions in passing that [Rabbi *Akiva* Eiger](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiva_Eger) (1761–1837, modern-day Austria and Poland), when asked how he had achieved his own greatness, replied that had striven to emulate [the *Rashba*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_ben_Aderet) (1235–1310, modern-day Spain). I see the same story, with no further detail, at [`Aish.com`](http://www.aish.com/tp/b/1-min-vort/292002371.html).

Was there something specific about the *Rashba* that he strove to emulate, or just his generally being a *tzadik* (good person)? If the latter, why did he strive to emulate the *Rashba* specifically? There had been many great rabbis over the years. And if the former, what was it about the *Rashba* that he strove to emulate, and why did he choose that trait specifically to strive to emulate?

Comment: This is (probably) not the source, but the Chazon Ish said about him that "R' Akiva Eiger could have been born in the Rashba'a generation, but Hashem had mercy on us and gave us R' Akiva Eiger in our generation." (Wikipedia)

Comment: @msh210. Question about your question. I struggle to understand the meaning of this question. We know that the Rashba was the largest in its generation, the Rosh himself admitted his "superiority" that his responsa are a great treasure to understand the halacha and study the Talmud. But who told you that this story has not been invented by a poor spirit.

Comment: @kouty, even if the _Rashba_ was the greatest in his generation (and I hadn't heard that AFAIR), wasn't, for example, _R. Saadya Gaon_, or _R. Y'huda b. B'sera_, or _Ovadya hanavi_ greater? And the story may have been invented (though I'm not sure what you mean by "a poor spirit"... it looks like you may have translated an idiomatic expression word for word), and demonstrating its falsity would [make a good answer IMO](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2179).

Comment: (Unsure if qualifies as an answer hence a comment) In Me’oran Shel Yisrael (vol. 1 220ff.) the author cites a number of passages from RAE extolling Rashba demonstrating his high regard for Rashba, specifically.

Comment: In Sefer Maggid Mesharim parshad Vayeshev the Rashba is called the chosen one of HaShem. וענין ער ואונן נעלם מאוד כמו שכתב הרשב"א בחיר ה'

Comment: My best guess is that he strove to imitate the Rashba's method of learning. Why the Rashba specifically is probably a matter of R' Akiva Eiger's innate learning style and similarities he may have seen in the Rashba.

Comment: @N.T. And what's the Rashbas way of learning?

Comment: I don't mean that the Rashba's basic approach differed from other Rishonim; more that every person's mind works differently.

Comment: The Rashba combined the *mehalchim* of the *baalei tosfos* and the Ramban. Rb Akiva Eiger sought to combine the *mehalchim* of the *baalei halachah* and the *baalei ha'peshat*.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE if you have a source for that, that sounds like the answer - why don't you post it?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that there was something specific about the Rashba, that Rabbi Akiva Eiger strove to emulate.

The Rashba was one of the foremost scholars of his day, and one of the most prolific responders to Halachic queries. Rabbi Akiva Eiger, in his generation, had similar qualities.

The primary works of the Rashba, are his expositions on the Talmud, where he strived to elucidate the intricacies of the Talmudic discussions; and his Halachic responsa, where for the most part he responded to Halachic queries of a practical nature, basing his answers on his broad knowledge and understanding of the Talmud.

Rabbi Akiva Eiger's primary works follow the same pattern; expositions on the Talmud, and Halachic responsa based on the Talmud.